# Find list of additional urls in Sitefinity database

Tags: content-management-system, sitefinity

Does anyone know what SQL I could use to find all of the Additional URLs for a site in the Sitefinity database?

Comment: Do you know what the tables' schema are?  Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I was able to figure out the sql to use.  Please see my update.

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please post it as its own answer instead of an update and mark it as accepted so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a list of urls and the associated page and parent page (using the html_title of both) with the following sql.

```
SELECT ud.url,
pd.html_title_, ppd.html_title_ AS ParentHtmlTitle
FROM sf_url_data ud INNER JOIN sf_page_node pn ON ud.id2 = pn.id
INNER JOIN sf_page_data pd ON pn.content_id = pd.content_id
INNER JOIN sf_page_node ppn ON pn.parent_id = ppn.id
INNER JOIN sf_page_data ppd ON ppn.content_id = ppd.content_id
ORDER BY ud.url
```

The piece that was missing for me was that while the sf_url_data has a content_id field, it doesn't always correspond to the appropriate page. However, the field id2 in that table does correspond to the sf_page_node table which contains the corresponding content_id for the sf_page_data table.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ultimately figured out for our scenario. The query by wbg34 wasn't giving me the real result url's that users were actually navigating to, as that is determined by the page hierarchy you setup in sitefinity. So what I did was build the FinalUrl in the below query by going up a max of 8 depth levels, if you need to go more just add more levels to the query.

This query removes the special backend pages, and removes the preceeding "Pages" from the url in FinalUrl. It lists all redirect rows (IsRedirect = 1), or if you see multiple urls on a page with (IsRedirect = 0), that means it's an alternate URL to that page and not a redirect.

```
select right(
stuff(FinalUrl,len(finalurl),1,''), len(finalurl)-6) --Remove trailing slash and Pages from beginning of URL
, url RedirectUrl, redirect IsRedirect, title_ as Title from (
select 
concat(ppn8.url_name_ + '/',ppn7.url_name_ + '/',ppn6.url_name_ + '/',ppn5.url_name_ + '/', ppn4.url_name_+ '/', ppn3.url_name_+ '/', ppn2.url_name_+ '/', ppn.url_name_+ '/', pn.url_name_+ '/')
FinalUrl, ud.url, ud.redirect, pn.title_ from sf_url_data ud 
INNER JOIN sf_page_node pn ON ud.id2 = pn.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn ON pn.parent_id = ppn.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn2 ON ppn.parent_id = ppn2.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn3 ON ppn2.parent_id = ppn3.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn4 ON ppn3.parent_id = ppn4.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn5 ON ppn4.parent_id = ppn5.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn6 ON ppn5.parent_id = ppn6.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn7 ON ppn6.parent_id = ppn7.id
left outer join sf_page_node ppn8 ON ppn7.parent_id = ppn8.id
) a
where FinalUrl not like 'Backend%'
order by FinalUrl
```

Progresses knowledge base articles give these additional pointers, but don't provide the final url of the page.

```
--PageName, PageUrl, EnableMultipleUrl, SearchEngineTitle 
SELECT pn.[title_]              AS PageName, 
       pn.[url_name_]           AS PageUrl, 
       pn.[allow_multiple_urls] AS EnableMultipleUrl, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   (SELECT url, 
                       Row_number() 
                         OVER( 
                           partition BY url 
                           ORDER BY url DESC) rn 
                FROM   [dbo].[sf_url_data] 
                WHERE  id2 = pn.id) a 
        WHERE  rn = 1)          AS AdditionalUrlsCount, 
       pd.[html_title_]         AS SearchEngineTitle 
FROM   [dbo].[sf_page_node] AS pn 
       JOIN [dbo].[sf_page_data] AS pd 
         ON pn.content_id = pd.content_id 
-- if only frontend pages 
WHERE  pn.root_id = 'F669D9A7-009D-4D83-DDAA-000000000002' -- default frontend root id 

--PageName, PageUrl, EnableMultipleUrl, SearchEngineTitle 
SELECT pn.[title_]                  AS PageName, 
       pn.[url_name_]               AS PageUrl, 
       pn.[allow_multiple_urls]     AS EnableMultipleUrl, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   (SELECT url, 
                       Row_number() 
                         OVER( 
                           partition BY url 
                           ORDER BY url DESC) rn 
                FROM   [dbo].[sf_url_data] 
                WHERE  id2 = pn.id) a 
        WHERE  rn = 1)              AS AdditionalUrlsCount, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 Substring((SELECT ',' + ST1.url AS [text()] 
                                FROM   (SELECT url 
                                        FROM   (SELECT url, 
                                                       Row_number() 
                                                         OVER( 
                                                           partition BY url 
                                                           ORDER BY url DESC) rn 
                                                FROM   [dbo].[sf_url_data] 
                                                WHERE  id2 = pn.id) a 
                                        WHERE  rn = 1) ST1 
                                FOR xml path ('')), 2, 1000) AS [Urls] 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   (SELECT url, 
                               Row_number() 
                                 OVER( 
                                   partition BY url 
                                   ORDER BY url DESC) rn 
                        FROM   [dbo].[sf_url_data] 
                        WHERE  id2 = pn.id) a 
                WHERE  rn = 1) ST2) AS Urls, 
       pd.[html_title_]             AS SearchEngineTitle 
FROM   [dbo].[sf_page_node] AS pn 
       JOIN [dbo].[sf_page_data] AS pd 
         ON pn.content_id = pd.content_id 
-- if only frontend pages 
WHERE  pn.root_id = 'F669D9A7-009D-4D83-DDAA-000000000002' -- default frontend root id
```